# Kafka Streams : Multiple topologies in a single application

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to use both Processor API And DSL in a single Kafka streams application. In addition, how to build and run multiple topologies in a single application ( like 1 using processor API And other using DSL. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily mix DSL and processor API. 
How I understand you would like to build processing graph using both of those two methods, to do that for DSL you can call `StreamsBuilder::stream`, and for Processor API you call `StreamsBuilder::build()` to get `Topology` and than apply function to add Processor, etc.

Source code will be something like that:

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
builder.<String, String>stream("input1").to("output1");
Topology topology = builder.build();
topology.addSource("inputNode","input2");
topology.addProcessor("processor1", InputProcessor::new, "inputNode");
topology.addSink("sink1", "output2", "processor1");

KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
streams.start();
```

**EDIT1:**

You can build two *topologies* with DSL, running in parallel and listening to different topics. It can be done as @Matthias J. Sax mentioned with `KStream::transform(...)`, `KStream::transformValues(...)`, and `KStream::process(...)`. Code will be something like that:

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, String> input1 = builder.<String, String>stream("input1").transform(SampleTransformer1::new);
KStream<String, String> input2 = builder.<String, String>stream("input2").transform(SampleTransformer2::new);
```

Comment: It should be simpler to use `transform()`, `transformValues()`, and `process()` though: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#applying-processors-and-transformers-processor-api-integration

Comment: So, Can we have 2 topologies running in parallel and listening to different topics ?

Comment: @user1768610, Yes you can. I've update my answer with sample code.

Comment: @wardziniak: Thanks

Comment: this one does not seem like two topologies. this is two streams running in one topology